# How to remove azure file share old data from the azure storage account?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-storage-account, azure-storage-files

I have  3 months of old data which is stored on azure storage account ? Now i want remove the data
if it >= 30days
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following script lists files/FileDir recursively in a file share and delete the files older than 14 days.You may give the required day limit.
Refered from thread [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/482814/deleting-files-in-azure-file-share-older-than-x-da.html).

Refer [this](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdata-factory%2Fdelete-activity&data=04%7C01%7Cv-sakavya%40microsoft.com%7C19999c654e6c4e21b86708d9526e087d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637631455001085323%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=vlAkkcY6PYwHPiUdndFWIeDj3eBS8VBGb%2BxFhCOKaZw%3D&reserved=0) for the **best practices** before delete activity.

```js
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $key
 $shareName = <shareName>
    
 $DirIndex = 0
 $dirsToList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    
 # Get share root Dir
 $shareroot = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $shareName -Path . -context $ctx 
 $dirsToList += $shareroot 
    
 # List files recursively and remove file older than 14 days 
 While ($dirsToList.Count -gt $DirIndex)
 {
     $dir = $dirsToList[$DirIndex]
     $DirIndex ++
     $fileListItems = $dir | Get-AzStorageFile
     $dirsListOut = $fileListItems | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFileDirectory"}
     $dirsToList += $dirsListOut
     $files = $fileListItems | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFile"}
    
     foreach($file in $files)
     {
         # Fetch Attributes of each file and output
         $task = $file.CloudFile.FetchAttributesAsync()
         $task.Wait()
    
         # remove file if it's older than 14 days.
         if ($file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14))
         {
             ## print the file LMT
             # $file | Select @{ Name = "Uri"; Expression = { $_.CloudFile.SnapshotQualifiedUri} }, @{ Name = "LastModified"; Expression = { $_.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified } } 
    
             # remove file
             $file | Remove-AzStorageFile
         }
     }
     #Debug log
     # Write-Host  $DirIndex $dirsToList.Length  $dir.CloudFileDirectory.SnapshotQualifiedUri.ToString() 
 }
```

---

**(OR)**

Delete activity can be configured from **Azure data Factory**(ADF) by following the steps below.This require linking your azure storage account with  the  ADF by giving account name, fileshare name and path if needed.

- **Deploy an ADF if not already configured:**

[image: f1]

- **Open ADF and create a PipeLine with any name.**

[image: f2]

****`The Process is`** :*We get the metadata of the file shares in storage account selected>Loop through them>configure Delete activity for the files inside them older than 30 days(or say some x days)***

- 1. Search for get meta data >> select and drag to place in the area
     shown    and name the file.   2) Then navigate to Dataset(This data set
     points to the files in storage account),select new .  So select azure
     file storage>Name it  3) >>Select the format as csv  4)>>Link your account
     by setting up the properties > give the file path.

[image: f3]

- To get files older than or equals 30 days you can configure   endtime
  as **`@adddays(utcnow(),-30)`**

[image]

- Now we have to use foreach loop to iterate through the array of
  files. Drag and drop foreach loop from activities and connect/link the arrwoed line  with get metadata.

[image: f5]

- In settings ,Tick mark sequential box to iterate files  in sequential order.
  childItems is the property of getmetadata output JSON which has array
  of objects . So select Dynamic content for Items and configure as
  `@activity("Get old files").output.childItems` and click on
  finish. ( Here Get old files is the name of my get activity created
  previously )

[image: f6]

- In the Foreach activity ,edit the activities and set a delete
  activity as below.

[image]
[image]

- Go to the dataset where we previously linked our file storage
  account.

[image: f9]

- Create a  file name parameter and link it to delete activity by
  adding dynamic content for file path by selecting that filepath as
  `@dataset().FileName`

[image: f10]

- Then go to the delete pipeline and add the file name as shown.

[image]

- You may also add logging setting to link account and see the activity
  happening after the path is debugged.

[image]

**Other reference**: [clean-up-files-by-built-in-delete-activity-in-azure-data-factory/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/clean-up-files-by-built-in-delete-activity-in-azure-data-factory/)