# Azure Runbook not deleting Files in Fileshare

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-files, azure-runbook

I am trying to to use Azure Powershell Runbooks to delete files out of the Azure Fileshare. There are no errors returned, but the file is not deleted. The Automation Account has a Run As account setup that is not expired or anything and the script works if I run it from my local machine.  Looking for some advise on this.

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "" -StorageAccountKey "" 
$shareName = ""
$directoryPath = ".cloudconsole"
$DirIndex = 0
$day = 1
$startdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)
$endDate = (Get-date).AddDays(-32)

$dirsToList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]


$shareroot = Get-AzureStorageFile -ShareName $shareName -Path $directoryPath -context $ctx 
$dirsToList += $shareroot 
While ($dirsToList.Count -gt $DirIndex)
{
 $dir = $dirsToList[$DirIndex]
 $DirIndex ++
 $fileListItems = $dir | Get-AzureStorageFile
 $dirsListOut = $fileListItems | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFileDirectory"}
 $dirsToList += $dirsListOut
 $files = $fileListItems | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFile"}

 foreach($file in $files)
 {
   
     $task = $file.CloudFile.FetchAttributesAsync()
     $task.Wait()

   
        if ($file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -ge $startdate -and $file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -ge $endDate  )

     {
     if ($file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified.day -ne '01'  )
     
        {
         $file | Remove-AzureStorageFile
         }
     }
        if ($file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -lt $startdate)
        
     {
     
        
         $file | Remove-AzureStorageFile 
     }
   
 }


 }
```

Comment: Can you please say why in if loop , "ge"(greater than or equals) is mentioned at both start date and end date  like this >> 
  if ($file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -ge $startdate -and $file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -ge $endDate  )   ? If i am not wrong shouldn't that be  '-le' and 'ge' ?                                              
If you want the fileshares to be deleted older  than 32 days ,then you may refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542455/how-to-remove-azure-file-share-old-data-from-the-azure-storage-account)

Answer (score 0):

[BoxJumper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711799/boxjumper): As [kavyasaraboju-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15997509/kavyasaraboju-mt)  referred, below piece of script should help you.

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $key
$shareName = <shareName>
$startdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)
$endDate = (Get-date).AddDays(-32)
    
 $DirIndex = 0
 $dirsToList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    
 # Get share root Dir
 $shareroot = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $shareName -Path . -context $ctx 
 $dirsToList += $shareroot 
    
 # List files recursively and remove file older than 14 days 
 While ($dirsToList.Count -gt $DirIndex)
 {
     $dir = $dirsToList[$DirIndex]
     $DirIndex ++
     $fileListItems = $dir | Get-AzStorageFile
     $dirsListOut = $fileListItems | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFileDirectory"}
     $dirsToList += $dirsListOut
     $files = $fileListItems | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFile"}
    
     foreach($file in $files)
     {
         # Fetch Attributes of each file and output
         $task = $file.CloudFile.FetchAttributesAsync()
         $task.Wait()
    
         # remove file if it's modified between after last 180 days and before last 30 Days
         if ($file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-32) -and $file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-180))
         {
             ## print the file LMT
             # $file | Select @{ Name = "Uri"; Expression = { $_.CloudFile.SnapshotQualifiedUri} }, @{ Name = "LastModified"; Expression = { $_.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified } } 
    
             # remove file
             $file | Remove-AzStorageFile
         }
     }
     #Debug log
     # Write-Host  $DirIndex $dirsToList.Length  $dir.CloudFileDirectory.SnapshotQualifiedUri.ToString() 
 }
```