# How to remove files before a particular time period from azure file share

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, fileshare

How to remove old files from Azure storage account's ** File Share** .Any AZ CLI command or a code that clears **old files** from file share in Azure ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this power shell code :

> **NOTE:** Please check out the [Best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity#best-practices) before any delete activity for safety purposes.

*Example to delete  file shares older than 14 days by listing files/FileDir recursively in a file share :*

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $key
 $shareName = <shareName>
    
 $DirIndex = 0
 $dirsToList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    
 # Get share root Dir
 $shareroot = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $shareName -Path . -context $ctx 
 $dirsToList += $shareroot 
    
 # List files recursively and remove file older than 14 days 
 While ($dirsToList.Count -gt $DirIndex)
 {
     $dir = $dirsToList[$DirIndex]
     $DirIndex ++
     $fileListItems = $dir | Get-AzStorageFile
     $dirsListOut = $fileListItems | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFileDirectory"}
     $dirsToList += $dirsListOut
     $files = $fileListItems | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFile"}
    
     foreach($file in $files)
     {
         # Fetch Attributes of each file and output
         $task = $file.CloudFile.FetchAttributesAsync()
         $task.Wait()
    
         # remove file if it's older than 14 days.
         if ($file.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14))
         {
             ## print the file LMT
             # $file | Select @{ Name = "Uri"; Expression = { $_.CloudFile.SnapshotQualifiedUri} }, @{ Name = "LastModified"; Expression = { $_.CloudFile.Properties.LastModified } } 
    
             # remove file
             $file | Remove-AzStorageFile
         }
     }
     #Debug log
     # Write-Host  $DirIndex $dirsToList.Length  $dir.CloudFileDirectory.SnapshotQualifiedUri.ToString() 
 }
```

You may also try with [Azure data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542455/how-to-remove-azure-file-share-old-data-from-the-azure-storage-account/68576874#68576874)

**Reference:**

1. [deleting-files-in-azure-file-share-older-than-x-days | Microsoft Q & A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/482814/deleting-files-in-azure-file-share-older-than-x-da.html)